# Prepare a TFS environment for tests

Tags: sql, tfs

Just to make it clear, my objective is to reproduce an environment similar to a TFS 2013 that someone backup from.

The backup (full) was made manually from SQL cause TFS is reproducing an error in the attempt of it and I'm trying to fix this error in a test environment.

1. Which way should I use SQL to backup it?
2. How should i restore and map TFS in the new server to understand it?

Note: The backup was created by an user that does not exist on the test machine;

Note²: I have the .bak's files (Tfs_configuration, Tfs_DefaultCollection and Tfs_Warehouse).

I can paste the error log of TFS if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [whole process is well documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869(v=vs.120).aspx), it's easiest when you have a Full TFS backup from the Administration Console, that way you're sure to have all the databases in their right state.

The process to follow is quite extensive, make sure you follow each of the steps. If the environment you're restoring from didn't have the backup feature built-in (it was added in one of the update packs), then you can get it by installing the Team Foundation Server Power Tools on the Application Tier server.

To update the accounts use:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869(v=vs.120).aspx#UpdateNetworkService

It looks like you may have all the databases required, though it's possible there are more. To restore TFS to a new environment, you need **all** the databases that belong to the installation.